# Non-english letter in BufferedWriter

Tags: java, http, bufferedwriter

I've written a simple HTTP server in Java. I've a problem with returning data to the browser.

This write a returned content:

```
this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder()));
...
writer.write(this.getResponseLine() + "\n");
writer.write("Content-Type: " + this.contentType + "; charset=utf-8\n");
writer.write("Content-Length: " + this.body.length() + "\n");
writer.write("\r\n");
writer.write(new String(this.body.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
writer.flush();
writer.flush();
```

Method *this.body.getBytes()* returns "Witaj świecie", but in the brower is only "Witaj świeci" (missing the last letter).

Where is the problem?

Comment: It's likely related to the length of `ś`. I'm guessing if you had two `ś` in the string, you'd be missing two characters instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is: `this.body.length()` is the *character* count, not the byte count. With one UTF8 character in there, the `Content-Length` header will be too small by one byte, letting the browser stop reading from the socket before the HTTP message body actually ends.

Comment: You're right!. I've changed this line to
   `writer.write("Content-Length: " + this.body.getBytes().length + "\n")` 
and it started to works good

Comment: @Simon: I think you can have this even cheaper by omitting the `Content-Length` header altogether. Clients conforming to [RFC 7230, section 3.3.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) should determine the end of a message by the closing of the connection through the peer.

Comment: @Simon, you should specify character set explicitly when computing length, as you do in all other statements: `writer.write("Content-Length: " + this.body.getBytes("UTF-8").length + "\n")`.